# How can I print formatted messages using Ice Cream?

Tags: python, icecream

Sometimes we don't want to get this kind of `expression: value` format, but just the value, as `print` statement does. And why not using `print`? Just because after I can handle the control of Ice Cream, disabling all my messages, if I want.

I am using Google Colab (Jupyter Notebook).

I have the following code:

```python
!pip install icecream
from icecream import ic

func_name="init"
ic("function {} started".format(func_name))
```

And my idea is to get something as:

```
function init started
```

And I am getting:

```
ic| "function {} started".format(func_name): 'function init started'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible according to this github issue:

https://github.com/gruns/icecream/issues/145

Another issue is currently open if you want to follow:
https://github.com/gruns/icecream/issues/143

They recommend using

```py
print(f'Analyzing Folder: {folder}')
ic(folder)
```

This is because ic calls `__repr__` on the content inside the parentheses.

You can also exploit this by renaming your variable:

```py
from icecream import ic

function_started="init"
ic(function_started)
```

Prints `ic| function_started: 'init'`.